# Best dynamic data structure for 2d circle nearest neighbor

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, computational-geometry

The title is most of the problem. I have a set of circles, each given by a center C and radius r. The distance between two circles is the Euclidean distance between their centers minus both their radii.  For circles a and b,

> d_ab = |C_a - C_b| - r_a - r_b.

Note this can be negative if the circles overlap.

Then what is the quickest data structure for finding the nearest (minimum distance) neighbor of a given circle in the set?

Adding and deleting circles with "find nearest" queries interleaved in arbitrary order must be supported. Nothing is known about the set's geometric distribution in advance.

This will be the heart of a system where a typical number of circles is 50,000 and 10's of thousands of queries, inserts, and deletes will be needed, ideally at user-interaction speed (a second or less) on a high end tablet device.

The *point* nearest neighbor has been studied to death, but this version with circles seems somewhat harder.

I have looked at kd-trees, quad trees, r-trees, and some variations of these.  Both advice on which of these might be the best to try and also new suggestions would be a terrific help.

Comment: @NiklasB Right. That's why I said "Note this can be negative if the circles overlap."  It makes sense in this application.  If it helps, you can assume there exists a fixed constant that, when added to all the distances, makes them non-negative.

Comment: I must be too dumb to read, nevermind

Comment: Is the Center a 2D point or a 1D point?

Comment: @taigitanaka: I'm pretty sure this question is about 2D space (see the  title)

Comment: Are negative distances comparable (-2 is closer than -1) or they are treated same?

Comment: You could use Voronoi diagram for your circle set. It allows pretty fast searches. But updates may be slow, especially if you add/remove large circle above many small circles. This may be improved if you split circles into sqrt(n)...log(n) subsets (each subset - for circles of some distinct size) and maintain a separate Voronoi diagram for each subset.

Comment: @Evgeny: Wouldn't it then be better to just randomly assign newly inserted points to one of the `sqrt(n)` subsets and rebuild the entire diagram on each insertion/deletion? I guess this would give you something like `O(sqrt(n)*log n)` insert/delete/query

Comment: @NiklasB. Yes, that's a simpler way to do it. But in many cases updating Voronoi diagram has only O(log(n)) time complexity instead of O(sqrt(n)*log(n)) to rebuild whole subset.

Comment: Are you saying that each operation can take 1 second? Because that's easy to achieve with a simple linear search over 50000 points

Comment: @EvgenyKluev Do you mean the variant of Vornoi that has circles as cell mediants rather than points?  Then the edges are hyperbolic segments.  Can you give me pointers to how these work?

Comment: @Ante No, negative distances are not the same.  This distance measure when negative corresponds to penetration, and the pair with greatest penetration (most negative distance) should be returned.

Comment: @NiklasB. No I'm saying 10's of thousands of inserts, deletes, and queries must run in one second in a database of 50,000.

Comment: @Gene: That's what I thought :)

Comment: Yes, I mean Voronoi diagram that has circles as cell medians where edges are hyperbolic segments. Such a diagram still could be represented by doubly-connected edge list and still could use trapezoidal map as a search structure. Adding/removing a circle is not very different from the case of points. Fortune's algorithm can be adapted as shown in this paper: ["A sweepline algorithm for Euclidean Voronoi diagram of circles"](http://cg.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn/papers/cad_2006_voronoi.pdf).

Comment: Could you post a sample image/screenshot? What are the dimensions of the space in which the circles can appear? There are some image processing techniques that might help here, but I'm not sure I understand quite what the space "looks" like.

Comment: @Rethunk It's the 2d plane. No prior assumptions on domain size or circle size or distribution are possible.  A screen shot is not really relevant.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification. I have some notions how to solve the problem that are informed by (but not limited to) image processing-like algorithms, but it may be hard to explain without sample data. Anyway, good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @David Eisenstadt for the idea of a 3d search structure.  This is part of the best answer, though his strange metric is not needed.

The key is to look in detail at how nearest neighbor search works. I'll show this for quadrees. Kd-trees with k=3 are similar. Here is pseudocode:

```
# Let nearest_info be a record containing the current nearest neighbor (or nil 
# if none yet) and the distance from point to that nearest neighbor.
def find_nearest_neighbor(node, target, nearest_info)
  if node is leaf
    update nearest_info using target and the points found in this leaf
  else
    for each subdivision S of node
      if S contains any point P where dist(P,T) < nearest_info.distance,
        find_neareast(S, target, nearest_info)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When this is done, `nearest_info` contains the nearest neighbor and its distance.

The key is `if S contains any point P where dist(P,T) < nearest_info.distance`.  In a 3d space, of `(x,y,r)` triples that describe circles, we have

```
def dist(P,T)
  return sqrt( (P.x - T.x)^2 + (P.y - T.y)^2 ) - P.r - T.r 
end
```

Here P is an arbitrary point in an octant of an octree cuboid.  How to consider all points in the cuboid?  Note all components of T are effectively fixed for a given search, so it's clearer if we write the target as a constant point `(a, b, c)`:

```
def dist(P)
  return sqrt( (P.x - a)^2 + (P.y - b)^2 ) - P.r
end
```

Where we have left out `c = T.r` completely because it can be subtracted out of the minimum distance after the algorithm is complete.  In other words, the radius of the target does not affect the result.

With this it is pretty easy to see that the `P` we need to obtain minimum dist to the cuboid is Euclidean closest to the target with respect to x and y and with the max represented radius.  This is very easy and quick to compute: a 2d point-rectangle distance and a 1d `max` operation.

In hindsight all this is obvious, but it took a while to see it from the right point of view. Thanks for the ideas.

Answer (score 7):

[Cover trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_tree) are another possibility for a proximity structure. They don't support deletes (?), but you can soft delete and rebuild in the background to keep the garbage from piling up, which may be a useful technique for the other structures.

There's a reduction from the 2D circle problem to the 3D point problem with a funky metric that goes like this. (The proximity structures that you named should be adaptable.) Map a circle centered at (x, y) with radius r to the point (x, y, r). Define the length of a vector (dx, dy, dz) to be sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2) + abs(dz). This induces a metric. To find the circle nearest to a center (x, y) (the radius of the query circle is not relevant), do a proximity search at (x, y, R), where R is greater than or equal to the maximum radius of a circle (it may be possible to modify your proximity structure so that it's not necessary to track R).

From my experience implementing kd-trees and Voronoi diagrams on points, it will be significantly easier to implement kd-trees from scratch. Even if you reuse someone else's robust geometric primitives (and please do, to save your sanity if you go this route), the degenerate edge cases of Voronoi/point location take time to get right.

Comment: This is a good answer: the funky metric is something I hadn't considered.  I've been diverted from this problem for a while.  Must figure out if I'll accept this or offer a bounty to get more attention. Either way I appreciate your thought.

Comment: I think you have a sign error. The distance is sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2) - abs(dz). Note that abs(dz) is subtracted, not added.

Comment: @ScottSmedley That's not a metric. We get the large circles to be closer by querying the near neighbors of a point with a large z coordinate.

Comment: Hi @DavidEisenstat, What am I missing? If my tree has 2 circles : p1 @ (0,0) with r=8 and p2 @ (10,0) with r=1 and we're searching for the nearest circle to point (7,0) ... adding abs(dz) will cause the algorithm to choose p2 as the nearest circle. Whereas, due to the larger radius, p1 is actually closer.

Comment: @ScottSmedley Circle 1 has coordinates (0,0,8). Circle 2 has coordinates (10,0,1). The query point has coordinates (7,0,8), where 8 comes from the max of the radii of the circles. Distance to 1 is sqrt((7-0)^2 + (0-0)^2) + |8-8| = 7. Distance to 2 is sqrt((7-10)^2 + (0-0)^2) + |8-1| = 10.

Comment: Thanks for explaining @DavidEisenstat. So both approaches appear to work. I am curious to understand the aversion to using a negative distance, especially as it requires knowing the maximum radii. Can I trouble you to elaborate?

Comment: @ScottSmedley Cover trees need points in a [metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111588/discussion-between-scott-smedley-and-david-eisenstat).

Answer (score 2):

I propose the following heuristic using a KD-Tree or something else that allows for O(log N) nearest neighbor. Instead of using a single point and a radius to represented a circle. Use k equidistant points on a circle itself, *plus the center of the circle, otherwise you might have issues with a small circle inside of a large circle*. It's the same the same idea as using a regular polygon of k vertices to represent a circle. It is then possible to take one vertex and find it's nearest neighbor (ignoring the vertices on the same circle) to find an approximation as to what is the closest circle based on the closest regular polygon.

The performances are as followed:

Create the KD-Tree: O(kN log kN)

Remove/add Circle to KD-Tree: O(k log kN)
-Add or remove all k points of a circle within the KD-Tree

Nearest Circle query (Circle): O(k log kN)
-This is done by first removing all k points of the circle (O(k log kN)) as it's not terribly useful to find out that the nearest neighbor of a circle is unsurprisingly, the circle itself. Then for each k points in the circle, find the nearest neighbor (O(k log kN)). Once the nearest neighbors are found, the actual nearest (to within some error) is the the one with the smallest distance (after calculating the true distance based on point and radius) (O(1)).

I'd suggest either using k = log(N) if you prefer it to be fast or k = sqrt(N) if you prefer it to be accurate.

Also, it's possible I haven't considered some special case that causes issues, so watch out for them.

Comment: True enough, seems I neglected that one. I was looking at the sweep-line algorithm. I'll remove that part of the answer. I'll leave the answer though as it might still be useful as an approximation (perhaps to someone else who sees this question with a larger data-set).

Comment: I actually meant `O(n^(1/2) log n)` :)

Comment: I'm thinking your previous value of O(N^(3/2)*log N) was correct as far as building the data structure, with O(N^(1/2) * log N) queries. This algorithm has the same big O in the case of k=sqrt(N), but has a better run time at the cost of accuracy (more so with large circles or highly clustered circles) if k=log(N).

Comment: Well building time is `O(n * log n)`, but what I meant was query/update time.

Comment: Again, it seems I skimmed over some details. There is still the query time. After reviewing the differences again, it seems the only major benefit is the actual nearest neighbor operation which can be done in O(log(N) * log N) if k=O(log N), rather than O(sqrt(N) * log N). Inserts and deletes with the other approach can be done in O(log N), at a cost of O(N) space by tracking which diagram each circle is inserted into via map or dictionary. While this one nearest neighbor/insert/delete are all O(k*log(N)). Still someone may find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a guarantee that circles don't have large radius, at least that maximum radius (R) is significantly smaller than area where circles are positioned, than I think it can be covered with standard space partitioning and nearest neighbour search.

When searching for circle in a set that has minimal distance to given circle, than radius of given circle doesn't matter (distance definition.) Because of that it is same if only center (point) is compared to set of circles.

With that it is enough to store set of circles in space partition structure only by there centers (set of points.) Circle adding and deleting is done in standard way for points. Finding of nearest circle to given point can be done in two step:

- find nearest center to given point P. Say circle C with center c and radius r.
- center of circle that is closer to P, by your distance, can be only in ring around P with inner radius r and outer radius R-d(P,c). It is enough to search partitions that intersect that ring for candidates.

It is possible to optimize search by combining these two steps. In first step, some of partitions of interest are already visited. By storing which partitions are visited, and circle with minimal distance found in these partitions, search in second step can be reduced.